# Fail2ban not working on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, fail2ban

I noticed a bunch of those [w00tw00t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897993/am-i-being-hacked) requests coming to my Ubuntu 12.04 server and so I installed fail2ban. I followed [these instructions](http://www.userdel.com/post/18618537324/block-w00tw00t-scans-with-fail2ban) on setting up Fail2ban against w00tw00t requests. I made sure to name the files properly, and restart fail2ban after the configuration was changed.

I tested by typing in various `w00tw00t` parameters in my URL just like the attackers do, but none would ban me. I did not add my IP to a list of ignore. I even tried from my phone, still no ban.

In jail.conf I have the following located in /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

```
[w00tw00t-scans]

enabled  = true

action   = iptables-allports

sendmail-whois[name=SSH, dest=ubuntu, sender=fail2ban@mail.com]

filter   = w00tw00t

logpath  = /var/log/apache2/access.log

maxretry = 1

bantime  = 120  #testing so that I can verify and not be banned for a day!
```

Here is w00tw00t filter located in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/w00tw00t.conf

```
#block w00tw00t scans of all variations

[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> .*”GET \/w00tw00t*

ignoreregex =
```

I verified that the log path is set correctly by typing in an obscure parameter in my URL, then checked access.log and sure enough it was there. I also made sure to restart fail2ban afterward I added the rules.

Is there any other setup I need to do out of the box with fail2ban? After I installed the only thing I did was add the filter and the wootwoot bit to jail.conf. I checked to make sure it's running by typing `/etc/init.d/fail2ban start` and it responds with `* Socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock is present`

**edit - just showing what the request looks like on /var/log/apache2/access.log**

Here's a malicious request

```
67.215.248.8 - - [12/Feb/2014:18:59:42 +0000] "GET /w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:) HTTP/1.1" 404 1997 "-" "ZmEu"
```

And here's a request I made

```
My.IP.Address - - [12/Feb/2014:21:41:13 +0000] "GET /w00tw00t HTTP/1.1" 404 1928 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those quotes `”` don't look right to me did you use a proper text editor to write your regex ? Try

```
Failregex = ^<HOST> .*"GET /w00tw00t.*"
```

Which according to fail2ban-regex finds the  in both your examples.

Comment: Nope, just tried again with the new regex. Still not banned!

Comment: @user1104854: Show us a line from the log you're scanning then

Comment: I updated my post with a malicious request and one that I just made.

Comment: @user1104854: updated my answer

Comment: Is there an easy way to cover SSL with this too, or should I just make another rule and use ssl_access.log for that one?

Comment: @user1104854: It's hidden in the documentation but logpath takes wildcards so you could try `/var/log/apache2/*access.log`.

Comment: @lian adding the wildcard worked for ssl. Thank you so much!